# Fibonacci Bit Representation Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, fibonacci

I already have the following functions

```
toBin, auxBin :: Integer -> [Integer]
toBin 0 = [0]
toBin n = reverse (auxBin n)

auxBin 0 = []
auxBin n = n `mod` 2 : auxBin (n `div` 2)

fib :: Int -> Integer
fib n = fibs !! n
  where
    fibs = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)

fibonacci = [fib n | n <- [0..]]
```

But when I map the Fibonacci list with the `toBin` function, I obtained an incorrect list:

Becuase, I obtained this:

```
[[0],[1],[1],[1,0],[1,1],[1,0,1],[1,0,0,0],[1,1,0,1],[1,0,1,0,1],[1,0,0,0,1,0]]
```

But, I want this:

```
[0,1,10,101,1010,10101,101010,1010101,10101010,101010101]
```

Could you help me?

Comment: It is unclear what your expect result type is. Is it supposed to be a list of strings?

Comment: What does the list that you want have to do with fibonacci numbers?

Comment: Btw, for better efficiency drop the `fib` function with the indexed access and just use `fibonacci = fibs`

Comment: The two lists do not match...

Comment: The first list is in fact *semantically* correct, the last one is incorrect, there you only shift a zero and a one at the right end into the binary representation.

Comment: Thanks. But, I have to obtained this succession 0, 1, 10, 101, 1010, 10101, 101010, 1010101, 10101010, 101010101, 1010101010,.. by Fibonacci (oeis.org/A056830) In this web it is explained how, but I can't transpose to Haskell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idea could be to represent binary values in decimal notation. So we "transform" `2` into `10`.

We can do that by writing a recursive function:

```
bintodec :: Integral i => i -> i
bintodec 0 = 0
bintodec i = (mod i 2) + 10 * bintodec (div i 2)
```

This only works for positive values, but that is not really a problem here, since Fibonacci numbers are positive numbers.

Now we already have a definition of the Fibonacci numbers, like in your answer:

```
fibs :: Num n => [n]
fibs = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)
```

So the only thing we still have to do is `map` every elements of `fibs` with `bintodec`:

```
binfibs :: Integral i => [i]
binfibs = map bintodec fibs
```

The first 15 numbers are then:

```
Prelude> take 15 binfibs
[0,1,1,10,11,101,1000,1101,10101,100010,110111,1011001,10010000,11101001,101111001]
```

The nice thing is here that we do not use any binary lists to process it, but keep working in the integer world, which is usually more safe.

---

Based on the second list however, this has nothing to do with Fibonacci numbers. There you start with `0`, and you then shift a zero or a one in at the right end of the number.

We can use `iterate` for this:

```
iterate (\x -> 10 * x + 1-(mod x 2)) 0
```

which produces:

```
Prelude> take 15 $ iterate (\x -> 10 * x + 1-(mod x 2)) 0
[0,1,10,101,1010,10101,101010,1010101,10101010,101010101,1010101010,10101010101,101010101010,1010101010101,10101010101010]
```

Comment: Thanks.  But, I have to obtained this succession 0, 1, 10, 101, 1010, 10101, 101010, 1010101, 10101010, 101010101, 1010101010,..  by Fibonacci (https://oeis.org/A056830) In this web it is explained how, but I can't transpose to Haskell

Answer (score 4):

There are many ways to add digits together in order to get a number. Here's one way. Probably not the most efficient way, but on the other hand built up from smaller functions.

Values like `[1,0,1]`,`[1,0,0,0]`, and `[1,1,0,1]` are lists in their own right, so what we can do first is to index them. The only trouble is that we'd like to index them in descending order. You can do that by reversing them, indexing them, and then reverse them again, e.g.:

```
Prelude> reverse $ zip [0..] $ reverse [1,1,0,1]
[(3,1),(2,1),(1,0),(0,1)]
```

The first element in each tuple is the order of magnitude, so you just need to make it a power of ten:

```
Prelude> :m +Data.Bifunctor
Prelude Data.Bifunctor> reverse $ fmap (first (10 ^)) $ zip [0..] $ reverse [1,1,0,1]
[(1000,1),(100,1),(10,0),(1,1)]
```

Now you can simply multiply the elements of the tuples together:

```
Prelude Data.Bifunctor> reverse $ fmap (uncurry (*) . first (10 ^)) $ zip [0..] $ reverse [1,1,0,1]
[1000,100,0,1]
```

Finally, you can add all of those numbers together. In fact, you don't need to reverse the reversed list:

```
Prelude Data.Bifunctor> sum $ fmap (uncurry (*) . first (10 ^)) $ zip [0..] $ reverse [1,1,0,1]
1101
```

You can put such a combination in a function and map your values over it.

---

A more efficient solution would probably be to just be to do a **left fold** (`foldl`), e.g.:

```
Prelude> foldl (\acc x -> (10 * acc) + x) 0 [1,1,0,1]
1101
Prelude> foldl (\acc x -> (10 * acc) + x) 0 [1,1,1]
111
```

Comment: Thanks. But, I have to obtained this succession 0, 1, 10, 101, 1010, 10101, 101010, 1010101, 10101010, 101010101, 1010101010,.. by Fibonacci (oeis.org/A056830) In this web it is explained how, but I can't transpose to Haskell